# Does there exist a group homomorphism $(\mathbb{Q}_p, +) \to (\mathbb{R}, +)$?

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, p-adic-number-theory, group-homomorphism

There exist homomorphisms from the $p$-adic numbers to the multiplicative group of real numbers (additive and multiplicative characters), but is there an additive homomorphism?

Comment: Do you want to insist on continuity as well? Also, due to convergence issues this isn't quite what you want, but you could consider applying the p-adic exponential first then taking an additive character of $\mathbb Q_p^*$.

Comment: Do you mean to rule out the zero homomorphism?

Comment: You should also write "there exist homomorphisms from **the multiplicative group** of $p$-adic numbers".

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned in the comments, as $\mathbb Q$-vector spaces (and hence also as abelian groups), $\mathbb Q_p\cong\mathbb R$. Thus, there are many group homomorphisms between them.

This "morally" should *not* be the case, since $\mathbb Q_p$ and $\mathbb R$ seem to have such different structures. One way to reflect this is to consider *toplogy*: there are no nontrivial *continuous* group homomorphisms $\mathbb Q_p\to\mathbb R$.

Indeed, let $\varphi\colon\mathbb Q_p\to\mathbb R$ be a continuous group homomorphism, and pick any integer $n\ge0$. Then, look at the restriction $\varphi\colon p^{-n}\mathbb Z_p\to\mathbb R$. Since $p^{-n}\mathbb Z_p$ is compact, its image under $\varphi$ must also be compact. But $\mathbb R$ doesn't have any compact subgroups other than $\{0\}$, so $\varphi(p^{-n}\mathbb Z_p)=\{0\}$. Since this is true for all $n$, we conclude $\varphi=0$.

There are no continuous group homomorphisms $\mathbb R\to\mathbb Q_p$ either, which I will leave for you to prove.